# Чи можна вживати в однині множинні іменники: кошти - кошт; гроші - гріш?

Tags: іменники

На сайті [uk.WorldwideDictionary.org](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B8) (Всесвітній словник української мови) пише, що: **кошти** - це множинний іменник, тобто має форму лише множини і вживається у значенні "гроші, капітал, матеріальні цінності".

Проте є вислів "за власний кошт". Наприклад:
"Порошенко **за власний кошт** орендував на Мальдівах цілий острів". (Взято із [ТЕКСТИ.ORG.UA](http://texty.org.ua/pg/news/textynewseditor/read/82209/Poroshenko_za_vlasnyj_kosht_orenduvav_na_Maldivah))

Аналогічно і зі словом "**гроші**". Теж на цьому ж сайті [uk.WorldwideDictionary.org](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%96) (Всесвітній словник української мови) вказано, що іменник "гроші" - множинний. Але є вислів **"гріш тобі ціна"**, де, ймовірно, іменник "гріш" походить від "гроші".

Отже, чи можна вживати в однині множинні іменники: кошти - кошт; гроші - гріш? Чим пояснюється таке їх використання?

(Виходить дещо не логічне запитання, бо одне заперечує інше, але на пракладах бачимо, що не все так просто).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Щодо слова *кошт*, то існує форма однини, парадигму наводить [Словник.юей](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%82). [Тлумачний словник](http://sum.in.ua/s/koshty) в статті слова *кошт* відсилає до *кошти*, але містить приклади із формою однини:

> 1. Гроші, капітал, матеріальні цінності. — Чого вже я не робив, як не побивався, скільки й **кошту** стратив, а все-таки нічого не вдіяв (Олекса Стороженко, I, 1957, 230); 
>      Власним (своїм і т. ін.) **коштом** — за власний рахунок, за власні гроші.
>      Ми все будували своїми силами, своїми руками, своїм коштом, не чекаючи
>      на допомогу із закордону (Іван Цюпа, Україна.., 1960, 59); На чиї
>      кошти (чий **кошт**) — за чий рахунок. Дома пояснили йому, що магістрат
>      прислав віз, і цей вивозив сміття цілий день на кошт Гершка (Осип
>      Маковей, Вибр., 1956, 359).
> 2. рідко. Те саме, що витрати; видатки. Шумне, легке життє [життя].. тягло за собою немалий **кошт** (Іван Франко, VIII, 1952, 234); 
>      ♦ Хитро-мудро та невеликим (недорогим) коштом —
>      розумно та з малими витратами. Хочеться так, щоб хитро-мудро та
>      невеликим коштом (Номис, 1864, № 3106).
> 3. у знач. присл. **коштом**. За чийсь рахунок, за чиї-небудь гроші. Тепер на Україні розгорнулось будівництво шкіл-інтернатів коштом колгоспів
>      (Радянська Україна, 4.VI 1959, 1);  //  Використовуючи що-небудь; за
>      рахунок чогось. Акторський склад змінювався постійно **коштом** припливу
>      нових сил з Києва і Одеси (Юрій Смолич, Театр.., 1940, 182).
> 4. заст. Забезпечення, постачання. Торгується [Кузьма Трохимович] і требує [вимагає] багацько: дай йому і **кошту**, і грошей скільки забажа
>      (Квітка-Основ'яненко, II, 1956, 6).

Щодо множинного іменника *гроші*, що є похідним від гріш, то його сучасне [значення](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=20272&page=685) ширше за [значення](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=20184&page=683) іменника *гріш*. В значенні "гроші взагалі" форма однини вживається як евфемізм. Множина від *гріш* матиме наголос на останньому складі.

Comment: Не слід будувати свою відповідь лише на slovnyk.ua. Річ у тім, що slovnyk.ua, незважаючи на його зручність, не лише не має жодного стосунку до НАНУ, а взагалі не зазначає ніякої інформації про власний колектив авторів/редакторів (я маю на увазі орфографічну частину slovnyk.ua (тлумачну він бере із СУМ-11)). Тобто, хоч slovnyk.ua часто містить корисну інформацію, але довіряти йому можна лише якщо ця інформація дублюється в інших словниках (за які хоч хтось відповідає).

Comment: «Тлумачний словник в статті слова кошт…» — варто зазначати який саме тлумачний словник. Бо є СУМ-11 ([тут](http://sum.in.ua), [тут](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/slovnyk_ukrainskoi_movy_v_11_tomakh) і також у slovnyk.net), є СУМ-20 ([тут](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index)), є ВЕССУМ (перший розділ [тут](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/а), [тут](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53392-0.html) і [тут](//ukrainian_explanatory.academic.ru/)) і, мабуть, інші (хоч більшість базується на СУМ-11, але у певних тлумаченнях є різниця).

Comment: Щодо орфографічних словників, яким можна довіряти… Я знаю [«Словники України on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) — він дуже незручний, трішки застарілий і містить помилки — але це все-таки УМІФ НАНУ. Але, власне, будь-які електронні чи паперові словники, де зазначені колектив авторів / редакційна колегія (а не словник на example.com від самого example.com).

Comment: @Sasha, дякую за зауваження. Замінила посилання. На жаль, я за межами України, доступу до паперових словників не маю.